# Performance tweaks and optimizations for ASMX web service on IIS7

Tags: .net, performance, web-services, iis-7

My environment is: Windows Server 2008, SQL Server 2008, IIS 7, .NET 4.0, and .ASMX web service.

I am currently just using all the default settings on IIS 7 for the ASMX web service site. But I think there may be some **tweaks and optimizations** that probably will further improve its performance.

I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647786.aspx) on MSDN though. Just not sure if it'd apply to IIS 7 as well. So what do I need to do here regarding IIS 7 settings and configurations?

Comment: As a related side note, `Ants Profiler` is an awesome tool to help identify bottlenecks in code.  It'll pay for itself in a few days.  Also, using a free load-testing tool like `SoapUI` is worth checking out.  Both of these have helped greatly on my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main IIS 7 performance features are

- Compression
- Output Caching

> "IIS 7 provides a powerful, unified facility for output caching by
>   integrating the dynamic output-caching capabilities of ASP.NET with
>   the static output-caching capabilities that were present in IIS 6.0.
>   IIS also lets you use bandwidth more effectively and efficiently by
>   using common compression mechanisms such as Gzip and Deflate"

- [Configuring HTTP Compression in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771003%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

> IIS provides the following compression options:
>   - Static files only
>   - Dynamic application responses only
>   - Both static files and dynamic application responses

- [Configuring Output Caching in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732475%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

> In IIS 7, you can configure output caching to improve performance on
>   your Web server, site, or application. When a user requests a Web
>   page, IIS processes the request and returns a page to the client
>   browser. If you enable output caching, a copy of that processed Web
>   page is stored in memory on the Web server and returned to client
>   browsers in subsequent requests for that same resource. This
>   eliminates the requirement to reprocess the page every time that it is
>   requested. This is helpful when your content relies on an external
>   program for processing, such as with a Common Gateway Interface (CGI)
>   program, or includes data from an external source, such as from a
>   remote share or a database.